# How to use postgis type Geography with spring-boot and postgresql?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, postgis

I have a Spring-boot project with hibernate. Also, I have a postgresql database with postgis extension. I really want to make use of the postgis extension geography type.

Unfortunately, it seems that Hibernate does not support the geography type, only type geometry, which is unsufficient for my needs.

What should I do? Throw away the hibernate completely? Or to try to store one model without hibernate, and the rest could still be managed by hibernate orm? (Doesn't sound good at all)

Could I use some other orm with spring-boot that supports the postgis Geography type? Are there any of those?

What about going without hibernate? To me that sounds best option so far. What should I do to the Spring-boot project to not use hibernate, but to still use postgresql? I probably would have to write my own dao implementations then? If you could point me to an example of how that can be done, it would be perfect!

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193299/hibernate-spatial-with-postgiss-geography-type

If all else fails, just implement the type yourself in your own custom dialect.

Comment: Could you provide an example of implementing a type with own custom dialect? And if I implement that type, then does all my postgis special queries still work?

Comment: Check Hibernate Spatial [source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-spatial/src/main/java/org/hibernate/spatial/dialect/postgis/PostgisDialect.java). You'll see the geometry type there. The geography type would be similar. Not sure what "postgis special queries" are, but you definitely can register functions on geography type in the dialect.

Comment: I checked it, but still that doesn't sound trivial at all. It seemed to rely on the JTSGeometryType. A full example showing all steps from the geginning to end could help

Comment: Nobody said it is trivial.

Comment: Ended up getting rid of hibernate. And it felt so good... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up getting rid of hibernate that doesn't (didn't) support postgis geography type. Instead I used JdbcTemplate and pure sql instead. Works great.

Comment: Kudos on getting rid of Hibernate/ORM.

Comment: Hibernate slows things down and adds too much complexity. I also went with using JdbcTemplate. Can you post your code using JdbcTemplate?

Comment: Can you take a look at this question for me? no one has given an answer or comment for days https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262202/spring-jdbctemplate-update-postgis-geography-column