# Spring JdbcTemplate update Postgis geography column

Tags: spring, postgresql, postgis, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to update the Postgis geography column with Lon and Lat with the code below

```
public void updateGeoLocation(String lat, String lon) {
    template.update(
            "UPDATE property set geo = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)', 4326) where id = 'b15e7a7e-3b27-4a2f-b312-33ebbed594b5'",
            lon, lat);
}
```

But I get the following exception

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE property set geo =
>   ST_GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)', 4326) where id =
>   'b15e7a7e-3b27-4a2f-b312-33ebbed594b5']; The column index is out of
>   range: 1, number of columns: 0.; nested exception is
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range:
>   1, number of columns: 0.

I tried the following query manually and it works, but I am having issues getting it to work with JdbcTemplate

```
update property set geo = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.060316 48.432044)', 4326) where id = 'b15e7a7e-3b27-4a2f-b312-33ebbed594b5'
```

How can I update/insert lon lat for the Postgis geography column using JdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

I applied function ST_GeogFromText, and used it like this:

```
"ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(" + longitude + " " + latitude + ")')"
```

Notice the difference between ST_GeogFromText and ST_GeomFromText